# Javascript classList.add loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I use fullPage.js to have a full height backgrounds and I want to make my navigation change color if the current slide has a dark background.

I've assigned a class to the dark slides and after a slide is changed, it checks the y position of the dark slides and sets the isDark variable according to whether the slide in viewport is dark or not.
Then it should add class to the links in navigation, which changes their appearance.

```
afterLoad: function (origin, destination, direction) {
    deleteLog = true;

    // Dark slides  
    var isDark = false;
    var darkslides = document.querySelectorAll(".dark"),
    positions = [];

   Array.prototype.forEach.call(darkslides, function (app, index) {
        var positionInfo = app.getBoundingClientRect();

        positions.push(positionInfo);
        console.log("y position:" + positionInfo.y);

    if (positionInfo.y > -50 && positionInfo.y < 50) {
            console.log("It's in the viewport!");  
            isDark = true;
      }  

      if (isDark == true) {
        var navlinks = document.getElementsByClassName("navlink");
            for (var i = 0; i < navlinks.lenght; i++) {
            navlinks[i].classList.add("invert");
            }
          }

        else {
            console.log("It's not in the viewport :(");
      }
        });



        console.log("isDark:" + isDark);

  },

});
```

According to console logs, the viewport check and isDark variable work fine, the navlinks variable also looks ok (returns the list of elements as expected), but the classList.add doesn't add any classes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have this typo here `for (var i = 0; i < navlinks.lenght; i++)`, where `.length` is written as `.lenght`.

Comment: That was it! Thank you for the solution, but could you please send it as an answer, so I can mark it as done, please? :)

Comment: No prob mate. Questions about a problem that is simply a typo is actually [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. So no need for an answer.